# Kubernetes for multiple user app with specific isolated resource for each project

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Here is my scenario:

I have an application top of Kubernetes. I have multiple users in my application. Each user has it's own account that can create multiple projects. You can imagine each project is a blog. The question is how I can give resource to specific project and quota. By then I need to monitor each project for resource cost. I have already know some ways such as each user with specific container or pod that has it's own privileges. What would be the experienced way to differentiate project resources?

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, I see two considerations: 1) monitoring resource usage 2) resource quotas.

The resource usage monitoring is a bit more difficult if you are doing fine-grained monitoring. However, if you are simply giving specific users a quota of resources to use, you can use the **ResourceQuota** api object. Constrain each user to their own namespace (for logical isolation), and apply a quota to their namespace. They will be free to schedule anything within their quota.

See [this guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/quota-memory-cpu-namespace/) for an example.

Hope this helps!